# how to write sql syntax to get greater than and less than values from given data?

Tags: sql-server

I have a data in sql table column as below

```
Range
1000000+
2000000+
100001-250000
10001-11000
10001-12500
1001-2000
1001-2500
11001-12000
12001-13000
12501-15000
13001-14000
14001-15000
15001-16000
15001-20000
15001-25000
```

I need to show two values as columns in excel with below conditions

case when range is greater than - 6000 then count(ID) as Greater_Range

case when range is less than - 6000 then then count(ID) as Lesser_Range

I did case statement but result is not showing correct count of ID compared to when I count manually. please can anyone suggest me where is wrong in case?

Comment: Does this `Data`-table has two columns: `int MinValue` and `int MaxValue`? If nowt, why?

Comment: Please who your data structure, that is sample data with all columns available, and expected output

Comment: yes this is data in column with data type Float

Comment: As Tim says, your problem is caused by the fact that you seem to have crammed two separate values into a single column. Change your database structure and this question will answer itself.

Comment: for eg: Range 100001 - 250000 is greater than - 6000 (considering values after - symbol) then count(ID) is equal to Greater_Range column. would it be possible?

Comment: Amelia that doesnt make sense. what is `- 6000`?, Again, show us sample data and expected result.

Comment: I do not have permissions to change dataset and asked admin to do that and at the moment admin not going to change data structure. that's why I am looking for alternate solution.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: sorry I have edited my question it should be - 6000 not -6000. input Range is in the question I added. Output I need is case when range is greater than - 6000 then count(ID) as Greater_Range

case when range is less than - 6000 then then count(ID) as Lesser_Range. what I mean I have to show in report of how many IDs with Greater_Range and how many IDs with Lesser_Range.

Comment: nobody can solve this until you provide good sample data and desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you essentially want determine a count for the number of ranges which size is larger than 6000 and similarly which size is less than 6000.

You can create a CTE which splits the range string into a minimum and maximum values. Next you use a case statement to determine if the size of the range is in fact greater or less than 6000 simply returning a 0 or 1 (IsLessThan6000 and IsGreaterThan6000 columns)

Final step is to sum the IsLessThan6000 and IsGreaterThan6000 columns. The following example demonstrates how:

```
DECLARE @TerribleRangeTable TABLE
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Range]    NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TerribleRangeTable 
(
    [Range]
)
VALUES  
        ('1000000+'),
        ('2000000+'),
        ('100001-250000'),
        ('10001-11000'),
        ('10001-12500'),
        ('1001-2000'),
        ('1001-2500'),
        ('11001-12000'),
        ('12001-13000'),
        ('12501-15000'),
        ('13001-14000'),
        ('14001-15000'),
        ('15001-16000'),
        ('15001-20000'),
        ('15001-25000')


DECLARE @maxUnbound INT = 1073741824;

WITH CTE_RangeMinMax
AS
(   
    SELECT  [ID]
            ,[Range]
            ,(  -- CASE statement 
                CASE    
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) = 0 THEN CAST(REPLACE([Range], '+', '') AS FLOAT) -- If no ‘-‘ character is available then assume this is an unbound range on maximum. Simply replace ‘+’ character with an empty string and convert to float.
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) > 0 THEN LEFT([Range], CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) - 1) -- Get the text left of ‘-‘character to get range minimum and convert to float. 
                    ELSE NULL
                 END
             ) RangeMin
            ,(
                CASE    
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) = 0 THEN @maxUnbound -- If no ‘-‘ character is available then assume this is an unbound range on maximum. Set value to a large integer.
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) > 0 THEN RIGHT([Range], LEN([Range]) - CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) ) -- -- Get the text right of ‘-‘character to get range maximum and convert to float. 
                    ELSE NULL
                 END
             ) RangeMax
    FROM    @TerribleRangeTable
), CTE_RangeGreaterOrLessThan
AS
(
    SELECT  [ID]
            ,[Range]
            ,RangeMin
            ,RangeMax
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN (RangeMax - RangeMin) <= 6000 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END 
             ) AS IsLessThan6000
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN (RangeMax - RangeMin) > 6000 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END 
             ) AS IsGreaterThan6000

    FROM    CTE_RangeMinMax
)
SELECT  SUM(IsLessThan6000) AS Lesser_RangeCount
        ,SUM(IsGreaterThan6000) AS Greater_RangeCount
FROM    CTE_RangeGreaterOrLessThan
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have used temporary table and string function and got the answer correct. I will prefer your solution with CTE and JamieD77 solution as well. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN [Range] > 6000 THEN 1 END) AS Above6000,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [Range] < 6000 THEN 1 END) AS Below6000

FROM    (   
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%+%', [Range]) > 0 THEN LEFT([Range], PATINDEX('%+%', [Range]) - 1) 
             WHEN PATINDEX('%-%', [Range]) > 0 THEN STUFF([Range],1, PATINDEX('%-%', [Range]),'' ) 
        END [Range]
    FROM MyTable

) t
```

get the max value and compare

Comment: Thanks!! JamieD77. I will prefer your solution as well.